# PHP: re-declaring $_GET and $_POST in script

Tags: php, post, get, variable-assignment

In risk of sparking an opinionated discussion I ask the following:

Is it considered bad practice to re-declare `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables inside a PHP script?

I.e.

```
$_POST['var'] = 'someValue';
$_GET['var'] = '';
```

The reason is emptying variables on certain instances and thus avoiding reloading page and risk of sending headers multiple times.

Comment: The question would be what are you doing wrong to warrant changing the values of globals in your script.

Comment: If you "need" to do this, then there's probably a bigger issue elsewhere...

Comment: How come an emptying variable would help to avoid risk of sending headers multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's bad practice. You can achieve what you need maybe with a hidden input which gets a certain value in the event you want to ignore the $_GET or $_POST variables.

Comment: +1, I often do this myself, and it's also how Wordpress often solves this issue, so it's not a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bad practice, because it changes what others are expecting of these variables.

Debugging can become quite a hell if you start doing this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`The reason is emptying variables on certain instances and thus avoiding reloading page and risk of sending headers multiple times.`

There is a pattern called the [PRG Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which has been made to avoid the re submission of data on page reloads.

Comment: What does PRG have to do with manually modifying superglobals?